# Python: Multithreaded Realtime data stream from websockets not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have written a small program which fetches data in Realtime from websockets, performs some basic processing and appends it to a dataframe, the data from the dataframe is read in a while loop and is passed through generator to generate a signal based upon few conditions.

I want to perform all these operations in a multithreaded manner but it doesn't seem to be working can you please help ?

Full Code:

```
import time 
import threading
import pandas as pd 
from time import sleep
import time
import json
import asyncio
import websockets
import datetime

lock = threading.Lock()

# Define websocket address
SOCKET_SPOT = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade'
SOCKET_FUTURES =  'wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/btcusdt_210625@trade'

connections = set()
connections.add(SOCKET_SPOT)
connections.add(SOCKET_FUTURES)

# Empty dataframes to append messages from the websockets
df_spot = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'price_s'])
df_futures = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'price_f'])
df_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'pct_diff', 'Signal'])


# Receive messages from both the websockets in a parallel manner and append to dataframes
@asyncio.coroutine
async def handle_socket(uri, ):
    global df_spot , df_futures , df_results
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        async for message in websocket:
            if uri == 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade':
                data = json.loads(message)
                df_spot = df_spot.append(pd.DataFrame({'time': [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data['T']/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')], 'price_s': [float(data['p'])]}))
                df_spot['time'] = df_spot['time'].astype('datetime64[s]')
                if len(df_spot) > 2000:
                    df_spot = df_spot.iloc[3:]
                        
            if uri == 'wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/btcusdt_210625@trade':
                data = json.loads(message)
                df_futures = df_futures.append(pd.DataFrame({'time': [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data['T']/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-1]],'price_f': [float(data['p'])]}))
                df_futures['time'] = df_futures['time'].astype('datetime64[s]')
                if len(df_futures) > 2000:
                    df_futures = df_futures.iloc[3:]

            pct_diff = ((df_futures['price_f'].iloc[-1] - df_spot['price_s'].iloc[-1]) / df_spot['price_s'].iloc[-1])  * 100
            time_last = df_futures['time'].iloc[-1]
            df_results = df_results.append(pd.DataFrame({'time':[time_last], 'pct_diff':[pct_diff]}))
            if len(df_results) > 500:
                    df_results = df_results.iloc[3:]
 
@asyncio.coroutine
async def handler():
    await asyncio.wait([handle_socket(uri) for uri in connections])


def loop_in_thread(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(handler())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
t_1 = threading.Thread(target=loop_in_thread, args=(loop,), daemon=True)


# Generator for producing signal
def signal(ut, lt):
    current_state = "Outside market"
    while True:
        #pct_change = yield current_state
        pct_change = yield current_state
        if (
            current_state in ("Outside market", "Market exit")
            and pct_change >= ut
        ):
            current_state = "Entered market"
        elif current_state == "Entered market" and pct_change > lt:
            current_state = "Inside market"
        elif current_state is "Market exit" and pct_change < ut:
            current_state = "Outside market"
        elif (
            current_state in ("Entered market", "Inside market")
            and pct_change <= lt
        ):
            current_state = "Market exit"

UT = 0.85
LT = 0.70

s = signal(UT, LT)
next(s)


# Run function 
def run_strategy():
    global df_results
    while True:
        if len(df_results['pct_diff']) > 0:
            signal = s.send(df_results["pct_diff"].iloc[-1])
            print(signal)
   
            
                
t_2 = threading.Thread(target=run_strategy, args=(), daemon=True)

with lock:
    t_1.start()
    t_2.start()
    t_1.join()
    t_2.join()
```

The program doesn't run and gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It gets stuck waiting to connect to "fstream.binance.com" because you are missing the port.

The port is 443.

So you should use

"fstream.binance.com:443" instead of

"fstream.binance.com".